# Learning to program, Visual studio code can't find dotnet

Tags: .net-core

I installed Visual Studio Code and .NET, wanted to start a project and learn to code. I can't get passed a problem shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I've looked the internet but I didn't quite understand what I was supposed to do and what would it do. I know this might be an easy fix, but as I said, Im just learning.

Comment: open a new command window and try

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install the .NET SDK. Among other things it contains the .NET CLI (aka the `dotnet` command).

You can get the .NET 7.0 SDK from its [download site](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0).

There are external forces that can cause the SDK installation to be invalidated. Order matters. Typically, you should install the lower-level components first, and then their dependents such as IDEs and other tools.

If you're starting from scratch, you can avoid the issue (usually, but not always).

Comment: Thank you very much, I had .NET SDK 7.0 x64 installed already, but after I reinstalled it - it worked.

Comment: Cool. I updated my answer to indicate that there are reasons why this can happen.